# How to copy/paste text from PDF generated by cups-pdf?

Tags: cups

If I create a PDF from LibreOffice Writer using the `cups-pdf` printer on Ubuntu 16.04, the resulting document displays fine, but I cannot copy/paste from it because I obtain garbled text.

The problem is restricted to cups-pdf because if I print the same document with LO Writer's "Export to PDF" button, copy/paste works well.

Is there any special setting (e.g. encoding) that must be configured on the cups-pdf printer to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I confirm exactly same behaviour, and this is long lasting "bug" [1] [2], while author of 'cups-pdf' does not consider it is a bug, so existing patches are not going to be used upstream.

For Ubuntu, using mentioned PPAs should work, but i can't test it currently.

More skills need if someone use raw Slackware. For Slackware 14.2 and CUPS-PDF 3.0.1 [4], the patch [5][6] from [7] will not work, it is too old. During blind trial-and-errors, i try to prepare working one [8].

Note, you should install it manually, then very carefully install your new 'cups-pdf' file-by-file; i can't get to work provided SlackBuild and install.sh in any way, too few skills i have.
But the fact that finally problem was gone.

You should remove your existing PDF printers, and add one using manually provided CUPS-PDF_opt.ppd, optionally (to ensure) remove CUPS-PDF.ppd.

[1] https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/cannot-copy-text-from-pdfs-created-with-cups-pdf-4175440557/

[2] https://github.com/alexivkin/CUPS-PDF-to-PDF

[3] https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=658004

[4] https://slackbuilds.org/repository/14.2/office/cups-pdf/

[5] https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups-pdf/+bug/820820/+attachment/3878188/+files/04_add_pdf_passthrough_support.patch

[6] https://launchpadlibrarian.net/153781216/04_add_pdf_passthrough_support.patch

[7] https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups-pdf/+bug/820820

[8]

```
--- a/extra/CUPS-PDF_noopt.ppd
+++ b/extra/CUPS-PDF_noopt.ppd
@@ -31,7 +31,8 @@
*ModelName:     "Generic CUPS-PDF Printer"
*ShortNickName: "Generic CUPS-PDF Printer"
*NickName:      "Generic CUPS-PDF Printer (no options)"
-*1284DeviceID:  "MFG:Generic;MDL:CUPS-PDF Printer;DES:Generic CUPS-PDF Printer;CLS:PRINTER;CMD:POSTSCRIPT;"
+*1284DeviceID:  "MFG:Generic;MDL:CUPS-PDF Printer;DES:Generic CUPS-PDF Printer;CLS:PRINTER;CMD:PDF,POSTSCRIPT;"
+*cupsFilter:    "application/pdf 0 -"
*% cupsFilter:    "application/vnd.cups-postscript 0 pstitleiconv"
*PSVersion: "(2017.000) 0"
*LanguageLevel: "2"
--- a/extra/CUPS-PDF_opt.ppd
+++ b/extra/CUPS-PDF_opt.ppd
@@ -31,7 +31,8 @@
*ModelName:     "Generic CUPS-PDF Printer"
*ShortNickName: "Generic CUPS-PDF Printer"
*NickName:      "Generic CUPS-PDF Printer (w/ options)"
-*1284DeviceID:  "MFG:Generic;MDL:CUPS-PDF Printer;DES:Generic CUPS-PDF Printer;CLS:PRINTER;CMD:POSTSCRIPT;"
+*1284DeviceID:  "MFG:Generic;MDL:CUPS-PDF Printer;DES:Generic CUPS-PDF Printer;CLS:PRINTER;CMD:PDF,POSTSCRIPT;"
+*cupsFilter:    "application/pdf 0 -"
*% cupsFilter:    "application/vnd.cups-postscript 0 pstitleiconv"
*PSVersion: "(2017.000) 0"
*LanguageLevel: "2"
--- a/src/cups-pdf.c
+++ b/src/cups-pdf.c
@@ -60,6 +60,7 @@
extern int errno;

static FILE *logfp=NULL;
+int input_is_pdf=0;

static void log_event(short type, char message[], char *detail) {
    time_t secs;
@@ -427,7 +427,7 @@
    int len;
    cp_string setup;

-  printf("file cups-pdf:/ \"Virtual PDF Printer\" \"CUPS-PDF\" \"MFG:Generic;MDL:CUPS-PDF Printer;DES:Generic CUPS-PDF Printer;CLS:PRINTER;CMD:POSTSCRIPT;\"\n");
+  printf("file cups-pdf:/ \"Virtual PDF Printer\" \"CUPS-PDF\" \"MFG:Generic;MDL:CUPS-PDF Printer;DES:Generic CUPS-PDF Printer;CLS:PRINTER;CMD:PDF,POSTSCRIPT;\"\n");

    if ((dir = opendir(CP_CONFIG_PATH)) != NULL) {
        while ((config_ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
@@ -460,6 +461,7 @@
    cp_string buffer;
    int rec_depth,is_title=0;
    FILE *fpdest;
+  size_t bytes = 0; 

    if (fpsrc == NULL) {
        log_event(CPERROR, "failed to open source stream", NULL);
@@ -483,14 +485,39 @@
        log_event(CPSTATUS, "***Experimental Option: FixNewlines");
    else
        log_event(CPDEBUG, "using traditional fgets");
-  while (fgets2(buffer, BUFSIZE, fpsrc) != NULL) {
+  while ((bytes = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 4, fpsrc)) > 0) {
+    if (!strncmp(buffer, "%PDF", 4)) {
+      log_event(CPDEBUG, "found beginning of PDF code", buffer);
+      input_is_pdf=1;
+      break;
+    }
        if (!strncmp(buffer, "%!", 2) && strncmp(buffer, "%!PS-AdobeFont", 14)) {
            log_event(CPDEBUG, "found beginning of postscript code: %s", buffer);
            break;
        }
    }
-  log_event(CPDEBUG, "now extracting postscript code");
-  (void) fputs(buffer, fpdest);
+  log_event(CPDEBUG, "now extracting code");
+  fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), bytes, fpdest);
+  if (input_is_pdf) {
+    while((bytes = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), BUFSIZE, fpsrc)) > 0)
+      fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), bytes, fpdest);
+/* Commented out because decoding of utf16 PDF strings isn't implemented.
+    rewind(fpsrc);
+    while (fgets2(buffer, BUFSIZE, fpsrc) != NULL) {
+      if (!is_title) {
+        char *begin = strstr(buffer, "/Title");
+        if (begin) {
+          char *end = strstr(begin, ">");
+          if (end) {
+            strncpy(title, begin+6, BUFSIZE);
+            log_event(CPDEBUG, "found title in PDF code", title);
+            is_title=1;
+          }
+        }
+      }
+    }*/
+  }
+  else {
    while (fgets2(buffer, BUFSIZE, fpsrc) != NULL) {
        (void) fputs(buffer, fpdest);
        if (!is_title && !rec_depth)
@@ -513,6 +540,7 @@
            }
        }
    }
+  }
    (void) fclose(fpdest);
    (void) fclose(fpsrc);
    log_event(CPDEBUG, "all data written to spoolfile: %s", spoolfile);
@@ -761,7 +789,12 @@
            (void) fclose(logfp);
        return 5;
    }
-  snprintf(gscall, size, Conf_GSCall, Conf_GhostScript, Conf_PDFVer, outfile, spoolfile);
+  if (input_is_pdf) {
+    snprintf(gscall, size, "cp %s %s", spoolfile, outfile);
+  }
+  else {
+    snprintf(gscall, size, Conf_GSCall, Conf_GhostScript, Conf_PDFVer, outfile, spoolfile);
+  }
    log_event(CPDEBUG, "ghostscript commandline built: %s", gscall);

    (void) unlink(outfile);
```

Comment: I'm glad you were able to fix it, but the solution seems too complex for many users (including me).  If the author does not consider this a bug, maybe we should look elsewhere for pdf printing solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can also try this method. How about using the PDF export feature in Libreoffice. You can then print or cups-pdf or whatever you want from that point on.

Answer (score 0):

I think the real problem is not in CUPS-PDF. Not even in Ghostscript ..
After spending days trying to understand the real problem..why text is not searchable? I think I found the answer...

take a look:
This is my workflow:

- I have a server in the cloud with cups and cups-pdf running ok.
- I have installed in my computer an IPP printer (xxx.com:631/printer/My-Cups-Pdf-Printer)
- Now I can print any document from any application to My-Cups-Pdf-Printer and the file will be converted to PDF and stored in my server in the cloud.
- That's fine ....this will work perfectly.

Now the strange part:

- Let's suppose that I want to "reprint" a PDF file (my-file.pdf) to My-Cups-Pdf-Printer just to take advantage of PostProcessing and perform some tasks after printed...
- I can print my-file.pdf from chrome, safari, preview.app and AdobeReader.app
- The same file (my-file.pdf) if printed using preview.app , chrome, safari will generate a pdf file **NOT_SEARCHABLE** in cups-pdf.
- But the same file (my-file.pdf) if printed using AdobeReader.app will generate a pdf file **SEARCHABLE** in cups-pdf.

The problem is that AbobeReader.app (not the chrome extension) will include all Font Encoding correctly . And the default printer system used by OS in applications like safari, chrome, preview.app will not include this instructions.
The result will be a PDF without the correct instructions about the font encoding, position ....

I thought that the problem could be in Ghostscript (gs GSCall). But is not...
The problem is not in CUPS-PDF.
And even in Ghostscript..

The problem is the way that OS printer system generates the PS File then send to IPP Printer (My-Cups-Pdf-Printer)

Someone thought that the problem could be a bug in Ghostscript, but he was also wrong: https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=692450

I tried to convert manually a PS FILE to PDF using Ghostscript from command line and get the same results. PS FILE coming from AdobeReader will create **SEARCHABLE** text. PS FILE coming from chrome, safari , preview.app will create a **NOT_SEARCHABLE** text.

The same occurs in MacOS and Windows. And both PDF files printed in AdobeReader will create **SEARCHABLE** PDF in ghostscript and cups-pdf at the end.

The approach used by others to "fix" this issue in CUPS-PDF bypassing a PDF file could work in another workflow scenario (https://github.com/alexivkin/CUPS-PDF-to-PDF?tab=readme-ov-file) , since you are only bypassing a PDF file in cups-pdf before send to Ghostscript.

So in fact you are not dealing with PS (postscript file coming from a printer). In this case you are dealing with an already plain PDF file.